# Crash in Instruments but not in debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm getting weird behaviour in iOS10 where my app crashes in instruments but not when I run it in debug. The crash in instruments gives no information just outputs `<End of Run>` Oh and it all works fine in iOS9.

By extensive NSLog'ing I have narrowed it down to this bit of code, what makes this really strange is that adding the NSLog actually stops the crash, weird.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"template.draft IN (%@)", draftSet];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSLog(@"request: %@", request); // Crashes

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"template.draft IN (%@)", draftSet];
NSLog(@"predicate: %@", predicate);
request.predicate = predicate;
NSLog(@"request: %@", request); // Works

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"template.draft IN (%@)", [draftSet allObjects];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSLog(@"request: %@", request); // Works
```

`draftSet` is a bunch of faults so I'm thinking that either the NSLog or allObject causes the faults to fire, which fixes the crash.

Any ideas?

Edit: Turning off compiler optimisations resolves the crash, I guess this explains why it happens in instruments and not debug.